# JavaFX Webview throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: javafx, printing, webview, stringindexoutofbounds

On some websites the JavaFX Webview throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions.

```
        WebView browser = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        setTop(browser);
        webEngine.load("https://stackoverflow.wordpress.com");
```

And i get following output:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCFontImpl.getGlyphsAndAdvances(WCFontImpl.java:120)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidReceiveData(Native Method)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.notifyDidReceiveData(URLLoader.java:844)
at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$didReceiveData$102(URLLoader.java:819)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

On other URLs i.E. "http://www.google.de" there is no error.

Can i avoid printing this stacktrace or can i avoid throwing this error?
WebView loads all websites correct, but these stacktraces are anoying.